# OBS Audio MIDI Control

Tags: live, obs

I use OBS to create technical demonstrations, and had the thought:

What if I could regulate my audio levels using a MIDI Controller? The Korg NanoKontrol has faders that I could use to mix, but now the question is how can we feed the MIDI signal directly into the dB level of audio “layers”?

If anyone has any idea on how this could be achieved using existing plug-ins or even coding a new plug-in (I'm not opposed to that), I would love to hear it.